# Symmetric sums in a magic square

Tags: number-theory, magic-square

> Numbers $1,2,\ldots,16$ are written in a $4 \times 4$ square matrix so that the sum of the numbers in every row, every column, and every diagonal is the same and furthermore that the numbers $1$ and $16$ lie in opposite corners. Prove that the sum of any two numbers symmetric with respect to the center of the square equals $17$.

**Attempt:**

Such a square matrix is known as a magic square. The magic constant is given by $M_n = \dfrac{n(n^2+1)}{2}$ and thus $M_4 = \dfrac{4(17)}{2} = 34$. Now assume without loss of generality that our square matrix is

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & b & c       \\
d & e & f & g       \\
h & i & j &  k       \\
l & m & n & 16
\end{array}\right).$$ We see that $e+j = 17$.

How do we prove the statement?

Comment: How did you derive $M_n$?

Comment: @M.Van Note that the sum of the four rows is $n \cdot M_n$, which equals the sum of all the numbers $1,\ldots,n^2$. Thus, $n\cdot M_n = \dfrac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}$ giving us $M_n = \dfrac{n(n^2+1)}{2}$.

Comment: We have seven sums of opposite numbers which must be shown to be equal to $17$. Call these seven sums $A, B, C, ... G$. Using the fact that this is a magic square with sum $17$, it's easy to write down lots of linear equations in these variables, for example $A + B + C = 3 \cdot 17$. I wasn't able to find enough linearly independent equations to get a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $c+l=17+q$. Then$f+i=17-q$ and (middle two columns) $a+b+m+n = 34+q$. However from top and bottom row, $a+b+c+l+m+n = 51 = 34+q+17+q \implies q=0$.

So this gives us $c+l = 17$ and $f+i=17$. That gives the diagonals proved.

I had less luck with the side elements. These may need a numerical "squeeze" due to the restricted number of possible integers... below are some thoughts as I jotted them down:

Now set $r = e+f \implies i+j = 34-r$ then
$\\ d+r+ g=34 \\k+(34-r)+h = 34 \implies k+h=r 
\\d+g+h+k =34 \\c+g+k=18 \\ d+h+(17-c) = 33 $

...

Comment: There are only four other pairs to check though, right?

Comment: Yeah, (d,k), (g,h), (b,m),(a,n), and if you can get the first two pairs to work the other two follow by symmetry.

Comment: A 4x4 magic square remains magic when you cyclically permute two rows or two columns ... .

Comment: @OscarLanzi Except that this magic square also has magic diagonals which property isn't necessarily preserved

Comment: @Joffan I think proof by contradiction will work nicely. Did you make any progress?

Comment: @Joffan if you cycle one row or one column then yes the diagonals change. But cycling two gives you back the original diagonal sums, in a different order, in the 4×4 case.